# Simplify $\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have to simplify the following expression:

$A =\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$

> Answer: $\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}$

I am trying to find the constraints of $a$ and $b$. I think that $a^2-b^2 \ge 0$ and $a+b \ge 0$. How can I simplify them? (the inequalities)

Comment: Hint: $a^2-b^2 + (a+b)(a-b) \geq 0$

Comment: @Ahlfkushevich, I didn't understand.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: $$a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b) \ge 0$$ This is a product of two real numbers. When is a product nonnegative? When both factors are nonnegative or both factors are nonpositive. So, either $$a+b\ge 0 \text{ and } a-b \ge 0$$ or $$a+b\le 0\text{ and }a-b\le 0$$ Since you also have the condition that $a+b> 0$, the second possibility is eliminated. Therefore, you have $$a+b> 0$$ and $$a-b\ge 0$$

Comment: @Valeri you have $a+b\geq 0$ and $(a+b)(a-b)\geq 0$, thus $a-b\geq 0$ so the constrains are $a+b\geq 0$ and $a-b\geq 0$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, thank you! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Ahlfkushevich, I got it. You mean $a + b > 0$. It cannot be $0$ because it's in the denominator.

Comment: @Valeri right y forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{a+b}\right)^2-\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{\sqrt{a+b}}=\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}$$

The domain is $a+b>0$ and $(a-b)(a+b)\geq0,$ which gives $a+b>0$ and $a-b\geq0.$

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am asking for the constraints.

Comment: @Valeri I added something. See again.

Comment: $A =\frac{a+b-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{\sqrt{a+b}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{a+b}\right)^2-\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$. How can I continue from here?

Comment: $A = \frac{\sqrt{a+b}^2}{\sqrt{a+b}} - \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)(a+b)}}{\sqrt{a+b}}$.

Comment: A = $\sqrt{a+b}-....$ I don't know what happens with the second fraction.

Answer (score 2):

The constraints are indeed
$$\begin{cases}a^2-b^2\ge0,\\a+b>0\end{cases}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}a-b\ge0,\\a+b>0\end{cases}$$ or

$$\begin{cases}a\ge b,\\a>-b.\end{cases}$$

Unfortunately, you cannot summarize with $a>|b|$ nor $a\ge|b|$ because of the asymmetry.

Comment: $a \ge |b|$ means precisely $a \ge b$ and $a \ge -b$.  So we can legitimately summarize with $a \ge |b|$ and  if $b <  0$ then $a > |b|=-b$.  But perhaps your summary is better.

Comment: @fleablood: I see no way with a single comparison.

Comment: Was a single comparison the requirement?  Yes, I see no way with a single comparison either.  I was responding to you comment of not being able to summarize with $a \ge |b|$;  you can if you add an addition condition that if $b < 0$ that $a > |b|$.  But no, that is not a single comparison and perhaps does not satisfy your conditions of a summary.

Comment: @fleablood: the challenge is to find the most compact expression.

Comment: Fair enough.....

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$\frac{(a+b)^2-(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt{a+b}(a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}$$

Answer (score 1):

1)  You have $\sqrt{a + b}$ in the denominator before simplification, so you can not have $\sqrt{a+ b} = 0$.  So $a+b \ne 0$ and $a \ne -b$.

2) You have $\sqrt{a+b}$ before simplification so $a+b \ge 0$ and by 1) you have $a+b \ne 0$ so $a+ b > 0$ or $a > -b$.

3) You have $\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$ before simplification so $a^2 -b^2 \ge 0$.

$a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ and by 2) we have $a+b > 0$ so $a-b \ge 0$ so $a \ge b$.

We have $a \ge b$ and $a > -b$ so $a \ge |b|$.

If $b < 0$ then $-b > 0$ and $a > -b > 0$.  If $b=0$ then $a > -b = 0$.  If $b> 0$ then $a \ge |b| =b > 0$ so we have:

> $a > 0$ and $a \ge |b|$ and if $b < 0$ then $a > |b|$.

...

Alternatively  $a^2 -b^2 \ge 0$ so $a^2 \ge b^2$ so $|a| \ge |b|$.

but $a + b > 0$ so $a > -b$ and .... same results of above.